# Run PHP file in Android

Tags: php, android

I am working on an app. There is user registration on that app. I just want to send an automatic email to that newly registered user. I tried it using JSSEProvider and GmailSender with the 3 jar files and some android libraries but nothing worked. I don't know if the tutorials were wrong but anyway I would like to try it using a PHP script. How this can be done? The file should be inside the app project or in an external link? I have no idea. And also, how the email variable will be the same for the PHP script if it is not in the same file?

Please help!

Comment: Don't, using PHP to send emails form Android is the worst way to solve that problem that I can imagine.

Comment: @AlexBarker so what should i do

Comment: SMTP is a pretty well defined and supported transport protocol.  PHP cannot send mail by itself and relies upon sendmail for transport.  It seems that `android.content.Intent` is the "built-in" method for sending email and probably what you should use unless there is a compelling reason to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question, I will show you how to do that.

You will need to use an [Async inner class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) to achieve this:

First, you need to create the String you want to use, we will make it a JSON string, this will allow you transfer values to the PHP server-side so that you can retrieve the values and send the email

```
String json = String.format("{\"email\":\"%s\",\"message\":\"%s\"}", email, message);
url = "https://www.example.com/app/sendemail.php?details=" + json;
new sendEmail().execute();
```

Below is the Async class that will send the email and return a sent notification:

```
protected class sendEmail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String str = url;
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(str);
            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }

            return stringBuffer.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("App", "cannot connect", ex);
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if (response != null) {
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("sent")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, ChangePasswordActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("token", token);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the server side [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) you can insert a PHP code that will retrieve values from JSON and send an email. Please see an example below:

```
<?php
    $details = $_GET["details"];
    $obj = json_decode($details);
    
    $email = $obj -> {"email"};
    $message = $obj -> {"message"};
    
    $msg = "A sample message";
    $headers = 'From: Example <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    
    // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    
    // send email
    mail( $email, "Example Message", $msg, $header);
    
    echo "sent";

?>
```